# Android XML Editor removes Unicode Escapes

Tags: android, android-xml

Hi i have unicode escapes in my xml files like that

```
android:text="&#xF100;"
```

but after hitting strg+shift+f for formatting it is replaced by

```
android:text=""
```

can i do anything about that?

Answer (score 0):

For java recommended is `\uF100` instead of `&#xF100;` - this is not displayed even in my browser if not as "code" [on fileinfo](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/f100/index.htm). Moreover, onfileino they posted:

> *U+F100 is not a valid unicode character*.

But back to question - are you sure your file is utf-8 and project is also?

Comment: hi i use this code with a custom symbol-font, and yes it is working with both versions, but the escaped version is better for reading

Comment: Yes, it can work with custom font only or with few mentioned on page I linked. Anyway, for java my solution should be used, so you can mark my answer.

Comment: but i didn't ask for a java solution, i need a solution for my xml file